# How can i save file with unique tag in Document Directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tags, nsfilemanager

**NOTE : File Name is given By user**

In one of my app, It is required for me to create file in Document Directory with any unique tag(It's better to give tag in String !).

I have searched for it but no luck. I knew how to create file in Document Directory But stuck in give uniqe tag to it.

If any body have done it then please let me knew how to do it.

Comment: you can add filename as date like `mmddyyhhmmss`. so every file name will be unique.

Comment: You can add a number as suffix like abc_1 , xyz_2 . Increment the number everytime you create a file and save that number to NSUserDefault. This way you can achieve what you want. I know you want string as tag but may be it can help.

Answer (score 2):

I have used time intervals to save unique files.

```
int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timestamp];
```

**EDIT:**

```
// Or As you said if the user gives fileName.

NSString *userFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d",USER_GIVEN_NAME,timestamp];

// Here USER_GIVEN_NAME is a string that is the file name from the user.
```

It doesn't matter if the user gives the same name because whenever you try to save a file, the interval of time will change and it returns a new time interval.

Comment: File name is Given by user. SO please provide other solution if possible. I think i need to update my que!

Comment: One more thing, How It can manage if same file will save again??

Comment: Whats the problem with this? You just add timestamp in the end like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d",FILE_NAME_BY_USER,timestamp];`. It becomes unique as timestamp can never be same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timestamp(as Kampai's answer) or you can append date with file name to make name unique like below code

```
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.calendar = sysCalendar;
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"mmddyyyyHHmmss"];
NSString *strDate = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",@"yourfilename",strDate];
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: `timestamp` variable is type of `int`. It will give you warning for type specifier in line `NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",@"yourfilename",timestamp];
`. Please replace `%@` with `%d`.

Comment: @Kampai sorry i copied your line :)